# problems with using virtualenv - source command and file not found?

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I've been following this tutorial:
https://python-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

when i type this into terminal:

```
virtualenv venv
```

A folder pops up in my directory, as expected, but there is no 'activate' file. only python, python2, and python2.7

I tried this only to get command not found.

```
AJs-MacBook-Pro-4:petrarch AJ$ source venv/bin/python2.7
-bash: ????: command not found
```

Sorry! please help this newb.

When I type in `virtualenv venv` again, i get this:

```
AJs-MacBook-Pro-4:petrarch AJ$ virtualenv venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /Users/AJ/Desktop/st...arch/venv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/log.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/backwardcompat/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 71, in <module>
    import socket
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/AJ/Desktop/stanford-ner-2014-06-16/phoenix_pipeline/petrarch/petrarch/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyInt_AsInt
  Referenced from: /Users/AJ/Desktop/stanford-ner-2014-06-16/phoenix_pipeline/petrarch/petrarch/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.11.6', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 960, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 902, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/AJ/Desktop/st...arch/venv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

Comment: Have you retried creating the virtualenv?

Comment: i just responded with the traceback i get

Comment: try source venv/bin/activate